# How do I make my list horizontal

Tags: html, css, list

I need to make my list appear horizontal at the center of my web page.

**This is my code:**

```css
.list-group {
   clear: both;
   display: inline-block;
   content: "";
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Home</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">About Us</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Gallery</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Contact Us</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Students ePortal</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried above code but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Its `display: table;` that gets the job done.

```css
#menu-outer {
  height: 84px;
}

.table {
  display: table; /* Allow the centering to work */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#list-group {
  min-width: 696px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

ul#list-group li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-outer">
  <div class="table">
    <ul id="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Home</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">About Us</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Gallery</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Contact Us</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Students ePortal</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.list-group {
  list-style: none;
}
.list-group-item {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Home</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">About Us</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Gallery</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Contact Us</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Students ePortal</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: 0 auto` to center container that holds menu, use `float` or `display:inline` to show your menu items inline.

```css
div {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-width: 720px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Home</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">About Us</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Gallery</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Contact Us</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Students ePortal</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ? please take a look at this

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
  <li class="list-group-item">Home</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">About Us</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Gallery</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Contact Us</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Students ePortal</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.list-group {
    text-align: center;
}
.list-group-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Home</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">About Us</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Gallery</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Contact Us</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Students ePortal</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Try this css:

```
.list-group {
   text-align: center;
}
.list-group-item {
   display: inline-block;
}
```